# sliding menu body wont collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i found this half page sliding menu and i think it it really cool. But i noticed that a part of the menu stays hidden behind the main body. And since i am still a beginner with all this i hope you could help me figure out what is wrong here.

I would like to see it happen so that when the menu slides open, the two sections appear, on the left is the realy menu part, and on the right is the adres part. 
But if the screen isnt wide enough the menu part collapses on top and the adres part goes to the bottom..

I think it has something to do with the:

```
<div class="cd-half-block">

.cd-half-block {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;   
}
```

But i cant figure it out! Pls help me..

[I placed it on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Burner/ssznu0on/)

Comment: Have you tried to patch it by setting z-index to 999 or something?

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssznu0on/4/)

1. add jquery cdn

   2. change this css:

```css
.navigation-is-open main {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Comment: Thats not what i was looking for. JSfiddle wasnt set to Jquery just yet. Im sorry. The problem happens when the menu "works". Then you will only see the adres part. But if you look at the code you will see that there is a "menu" part. But that is stuck underneath the main body

Comment: @SanderS you mean the black part when we click toggle?

Comment: @SanderS if my answer worked please upvote and mark the comment as answer.  Thank you.

Comment: The system says im tomuch of a newb to do that.. so its not that i dont want too.. its just that i cant!